# Trocar data-src por SRC

Tags: html

Boa tarde a todos!

Tenho uma dúvida, pode ser simples (ou não).

Tem como trocar atributo?

Exemplo, tenho uma tag img com um atributo data-src. Quero transformar esse atributo data-src em src.

Assim:

```
<img id="teste" data-src="link_da_imagem">
```

Quero por assim:

```
<img id="teste" src="link_da_imagem">
```

Tem alguma função em JavaScript/JQuery que faça isso?

Obrigado!

## EDIT

Guilherme, obrigado!

O problema é o seguinte, vou tentar descrever.

Tenho uma loja, que os produtos a amostra, ficam assim: http://image.prntscr.com/image/4b9f2d57b2734a38ad11ca8f86f53157.png

Ao clicar na imagenzinha pequena, a imagem grande muda (Muda no caso, pra qual imagem pequena você clicou)

Preciso, em vez de ficar assim, ter um carrossel ali, para passar as imagens para o lado, em vez de clicar na imagem e ela mudar. No caso, ficar assim: http://image.prntscr.com/image/5a895102389440d58526fc1e7f13361f.png

Estou utilizando o owl-carousel, que no caso o script é esse: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html

Na loja, esse produtos aqui: http://image.prntscr.com/image/4b9f2d57b2734a38ad11ca8f86f53157.png somente a imagem grande fica em SRC, as pequenas (lado esquerdo) ficam com data-src, assim o carousel não funciona, pôs ele mostra somente a tag  que possui SRC e não DATA-SRC. Se entenderam e puderem ajudar, eu agradeço, se não, agradeço do mesmo jeito! :)

Comment: Por que você usa `data-src` em vez de `src`?

Comment: Você usa alguma biblioteca ? Pelo padrão o certo é `src`.

Comment: Basta editar o HTML, não?

Comment: Olhe minha pergunta editada, se puderem, e se conseguirem entender. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

No seu caso pode ser dessa forma (Solução com jQuery):

```
$('#teste').attr({
        src : $('#teste').attr('data-src'),
    })
    .removeAttr('data-src')
;
```

Basicamente, você vai criar um novo atributo e remover o antigo, penso que renomear, exatamente, não seja possível.

Comment: Não adiantar sair postando um código, ele deve estar usando um sistema de carousel pronto, na logica deveria trocar de data-src para src sozinho, ou talvez seja só corrigir o HTML, não adianta sair postando respostas sem tem noção da raiz real do problema. Entenda como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme pela resposta, #EDITADO

Comment: @LucasCarvalho na verdade o comentário é para o Kenny

Comment: Guilherme, é isso mesmo que você descreveu, estou utilizando o owl-carousel, que no caso o script se encontra aqui: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html o data-src ja é do sistema, e não posso mudar elas para src no html, teria que ser via JavaScript.